# Interchanging summation with integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Is there any way to interchange between the sum and the integral:
$$\sum _{n=1,3,5,..}^{\infty} \frac{ \left[\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\cos(s^2)ds\right]^2}{ n^3}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$
my goal is to get a closed form integral **not series**, the integral in the bracket is the well known Fresnel cosine integral $C(s)$

Comment: BTW, the equation does not stand a numerical test: the lhs is 0.841078, while the rhs is 0.61685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the expression can be written as a (double) integral with the sum done.

Let

$$f = \sum _{n=1,3,5,..}^{\infty} \frac{ \left(\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\cos(s^2)ds\right)^2}{ n^3}\tag{1}$$

Now in the integral $i=\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\cos(s^2)\,ds$ substitute $s=u \sqrt{n}$ which gives $i = \sqrt{n} \int_0^1\cos(n u^2)\,du$.

Hence the numerator of the summand of $f$ can be written as a double integral

$$g = \left(\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\cos(s^2)ds\right)^2 = n \int_0^1\cos(n u^2)\,du  \int_0^1\cos(n v^2)\,dv\tag{2}$$

Now interchanging sum and integrals and have to calculate the sum

$$s_{i}(u,v)=\sum _{n=1,3,5,..}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} cos(n u^2) cos(n v^2)\tag{3}$$

the result is

$$s_{i}(u,v)=\frac{1}{16} e^{-i u^2-i v^2} \left(e^{2 i v^2} \Phi \left(e^{-2 i \left(u^2-v^2\right)},2,\frac{1}{2}\right)\\+e^{2 i u^2} \Phi \left(e^{2 i \left(u^2-v^2\right)},2,\frac{1}{2}\right)+\Phi \left(e^{-2 i \left(u^2+v^2\right)},2,\frac{1}{2}\right)\\+e^{2 i u^2+2 i v^2} \Phi \left(e^{2 i \left(u^2+v^2\right)},2,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

Here

$$\Phi (z,s,a)= \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^k}{(a+k)^s}$$

is the Lerch transcedent.

Finally $f$ can be written as a double integral

$$f = \int_0^1 \,du  \int_0^1\,dv \;s_{i}(u,v)\tag{5}$$

Remark: because of the symmetry in the arguments the double integrals can possibly be transformed into single integrals.

Comment: many thanks, another related question , I have the following two sums containing the Fresnel cosine integral $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left((-1)^n-1\right)^2 C\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^2}{ n^3}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{C(2\sqrt{n})}{n^{5/2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{15}$$ can I (using these closed sum) get a closed form of the $C(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: How is you $C(x)$ defined? Notice that $\int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \cos \left(s^2\right) \, ds = \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} C\left(\sqrt{n} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)$

Comment: $$C(x)=\int_0^x cos(s^2)ds$$ for the first sum,and $$C(2\sqrt{n})=\int_0^{2\sqrt{n}}cos(\frac{\pi s^2}{2})$$ for the second.

Comment: I repeat the comment which has vanished miraculously: also the results of these two sums are not correct.

Comment: If you like my result you could upvote it.